# how can i add entity on cursor position using aFrame

Tags: aframe, virtual-reality, webvr

i need to know how i can add entity on position cursor using aFrame

on click i want to add entity far from camera 2 meter away or something like that

or i need to know how can i get position on click event (x,y,z)

but the problem here i what to add entity on 360 photo and i using a-sky tag and i tried to get position using js but i Failed it's working on entity only

```js
this.el.addEventListener('click', function (evt) {
   console.log('I was clicked at: ', evt.detail.intersection.point);
```

for Example [see this photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUttI.png)

Comment: You want to place an object in a 2m radius on a sphere around you, or just in front of you ?

Comment: Thank you for comment.. I want on sphere. You can check this photo
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUttI.png

Comment: I want to import object On  sphere when i click with cursor on sphere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sky is very far away so the raycaster won't reach (default `far` value is 1000`).

You could do something like:

```
<a-camera>
  <a-entity id="clickPosition" position="0 0 -100"></a-entity>
</a-camera>
```

And then you can get the position to add entity via:

```
document.getElementById('clickPosition').getWorldPosition();
```

Comment: thanks it's work :)
edit : it working using object3D
document.getElementById('clickPosition').object3D.getWorldPosition();

Comment: but i have another problem here i can't create click event on a-sky

Comment: > The sky is very far away so the raycaster won't reach (default far value is 1000`).

Comment: i have problem on click, i have 2 <a-text> side be side, and when i click on the right text, the first trigger is on left and then going to right a text, how to make position event to be only on each <a-text>