# aframe get cursor position and set entity on that postion

Tags: position, cursor, aframe

i need to know how can i get a camera cursor position and add entity on that position  i check many solution as like
[how can i add entity on cursor position using aFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49435591/how-can-i-add-entity-on-cursor-position-using-aframe)
 here is my code example `

```
  <a-text font="kelsonsans" value="Puy de Sancy, France" width="6" position="2 11 0"
          rotation="0 15 0"></a-text>
          
          <a-camera camera-logger id="camera"> <a-cursor fuse="true" color="yellow"></a-cursor> </a-camera>
</a-scene>`
```

here is my JS code

```
  function getPos(){
     var cameraEl = document.querySelector('#camera');
     var WorldPosition = cameraEl.object3D.getWorldPosition();
     var pos = cameraEl.getAttribute('position');
     var rot = cameraEl.getAttribute('rotation');
     console.log(WorldPosition);
     console.log(pos);
     console.log(rot);
  }
```

but when i try to set entity position as per below out put it's not showing on that location because it's showing like position coordinates "x: -5.385803274229736, y: 69.90085100596048, z: 0"
but aframe position coordinates are difference Might be it's a ThreeJs Position please help me with the full solution

Answer (score 2):

### As of AFRAME 1.0.4, JULY 2020:

Kevin knows his shit on this topic obviously, but his answer didn't work for me either; I presume it's because of changes since 1.0.0 in aframe.

The only thing wrong was that `cursor.components.intersectedEl` does not seem to be a thing anymore. Still, at least for my case, that was easy to get around because I knew the object I wanted intersections from, and so could listen for mouseenter and mouseleave events.

Won't solve every situation, but for the next guy:

```js
var cursor = document.querySelector('[cursor]');
var elToWatch = document.querySelector('[gameboard]')
var intersection = cursor.components.raycaster.getIntersection(elToWatch);
var intersectionPosition = intersection.point;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to get the intersection data from the cursor.

```
var cursor = document.querySelector('a-cursor'); 
if (!cursor.components.intersectedEl) { return; }
var intersection = cursor.components.raycaster.getIntersection(cursor.components.intersectedEl);
var intersectionPosition = intersection.point;
```

I think in `master`, cursor event detail contains a reference to `getIntersection` so you can call like `evt.detail.getIntersection(evt.detail.intersectedEl)`.

Comment: intersectedEl not found in cursor plz explain in detail i am getting X,y,z position but might be it's a Threejs Float value not coordinates with Aframe